# Immutable classes in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, class, boost, immutability

In one of my projects, I have some classes that represent entities that cannot change once created, aka. immutable classes.

Example : A class `RSAKey` that represent a RSA key which only has const methods. There is no point changing the existing instance: if you need another one, you just create one.

My objects sometimes are heavy and I enforced the use of smart pointers to avoid **deep** copy.

So far, I have the following pattern for my classes:

```
class RSAKey : public boost::noncopyable, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<RSAKey>
{
    public:

    /**
     * \brief Some factory.
     * \param member A member value.
     * \return An instance.
     */
    static boost::shared_ptr<const RSAKey> createFromMember(int member);

    /**
     * \brief Get a member.
     * \return The member.
     */
    int getMember() const;

    private:

    /**
     * \brief Constructor.
     * \param member A member.
     */
    RSAKey(int member);

    /**
     * \brief Member.
     */
    const int m_member;
};
```

So you can only get a pointer (well, a *smart* pointer) to a const RSAKey. To me, it makes sense, because having a non-const reference to the instance is useless (it only has const methods).

Do you guys see any issue regarding this pattern ? Are immutable classes something common in C++ or did I just created a monster ?

Thank you for your advices !

Comment: One suggestion:  if your class is noncopyable and immutable, you may as well make `m_member` const.

Comment: Thank you. It is const in my code. I forgot it when I wrote the example. Edited ;)

Comment: Just be careful when using `boost::shared_ptr` not to construct more than one shared pointer using the same `RSAKey*`, or they will not share the ownership over the object with each other and it will be deleted when there are still shared pointers referencing it. I would actually discourage using `boost::shared_ptr` for that reason, unless you really know what you do, and use a shared pointer class that stores the reference counter inside of the objects instead (e.g. Qt's, or make your own).

Comment: **Correction:** I believe Qt's `QSharedPointer` has the same problem as `boost::shared_ptr` has. However, Qt has `QSharedDataPointer` and `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer`, which let the referenced data (the object) store the counter. The former implements [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and detaches (copies, but this will only happen if the reference count > 1) the object when non-const access to it is requested. The latter works more like an ordinary shared pointer, but you still have an option to call `detach()` if you want the data to be detached.

Comment: Immutable object does not have to be non-copyable, unless that is additional requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

Marking every object `const` from the factory obviates marking every data member `const`, but in this example there is only one anyway.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, why is your answer a *community wiki* ? (I didn't even know answers could be *community wiki* on their own). Just wondering.

Comment: @ereOn: Because I don't feel I'm contributing anything. If someone wants to add actual content to my post, feel free. It's more of a dummy so you can accept that you're right in the end.

Answer (score 9):

This seems like overkill. When you only have const members, the object can not be changed anyway. If you want to disallow copying, just make the copy constructor and the assignment operator private.

Comment: boost:noncopyable is more explicit. Looking at the interface you'll immediately see the  ": public boost::noncopyable" while you might not notice the private copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: But that brings in the considerable coupling overhead of Boost, when a perfectly good idiom - hiding the copy constructor and copy assignment operator - already exists. What is the benefit to the programmer? (The benefits to the promulgators of Boost are obvious)

Comment: I already use Boost **a lot** in this project (mainly for the `boost::shared_ptr<>`). Personnaly, I think inheriting from `boost::noncopyable` is more readable.

Comment: If you don't want coupling with boost, creating your own "noncopyable" is pretty straightforward, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Right on. I certainly don't want to reinvent a wheel that is a (distorted) reinvention of an existing technique!

Comment: I disagree (with the overkill part, I won't go into the boost::noncopyable discussion): even if having only const methods/members guarantee that the object will not ever be changed, returning const pointer makes it more readable for the casual reader. I don't need to know whether the class is immutable or not: I cannot mutate it since I was handed a pointer to const.

Comment: @DannyT: lol, I meant the opposite, but I can see how you interprete it.  Actually, I really meant to create 1 noncopyable so your class can inherit from it, just as boost does for you.